# Flutter PageView - Show preview of page on left and right

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to create a pagiewView in flutter that shows preview of the next page and the a preview of the next page as is in the attached image. How can I achieve that?[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to add padding and margin in the children widgets, it didn't work. I have some android background, in android we usually by adding setClipToPadding()

Comment: I'm guessing a [carousel_slider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/carousel_slider) or [page-transformer](https://github.com/roughike/page-transformer) is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I finally knew how to achieve this with `pageView`

```
PageView(
  children: items,
  controller: PageController(
      viewportFraction: 0.8,
      initialPage: 0,
  )

)
```

Comment: i want to display only next page ?can you help me on this

Comment: @MilanPansuriya Try setting `padEnds: false` property on `PageView` along with code from this answer. Is this what you want?

Comment: Is it possible to show a preview of only the right side and not the left side? I don't want both sides previewing on the screen.

Comment: Although this works, it forces you to use a huge horizontal padding which makes the rest of your UI look odd