# Flutter Horizontal List View Dot Indicator When Scroll

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want the listView to have a dots indicator, based on the first listView Item position same with image in Flutter!
Please help me! Thank you!

[image: Image link]

Comment: You should use `pageview` with dot indicator

Comment: I want that when I scroll widget, I wanna see full the second image, afterward the second image will replace the first image.

Comment: @redgreen You need to use the viewpager as Nilesh has suggested

Comment: If I will use ViewPager, space of two side widget will symmetric. And I don''t want it. I will combine dot indicators and ListView. And when I scroll widget then I will keep position of widget.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter PageView - Show preview of page on left and right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54328666/flutter-pageview-show-preview-of-page-on-left-and-right)

Comment: Thank you but this is not answer please see image [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRR9J.jpg)

Comment: Please help me! Thank you

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://gist.github.com/collinjackson/4fddbfa2830ea3ac033e34622f278824) example?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a ListView, it might make more sense using a custom scroll indicator. Page indicator are commonly used with PageViews since the current page in focus snaps in place. You can try using [scroll_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_indicator) plugin to create your custom scroll indicator.