# Flutter PageView - Show preview of page only on right

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am building a carousel where I want the preview page only on the right. This is the kind of result that I want.

[image]

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54328666/flutter-pageview-show-preview-of-page-on-left-and-righthttps://) question but it has previews on both sides. Can anyone suggest what I should do?

Comment: may be set the width of each carousel to 90-95% of screen's width.

Comment: @OMiShah I tried it but that doesn't work. That just shrinks the whole carousel down.

Answer (score 2):

Use `padEnds: false` property of `PageView` like this:

```
PageView(
  children: items,
  padEnds: false,
  controller: PageController(
      viewportFraction: 0.8,
      initialPage: 0,
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to use viewportFraction in PageController.
Please refer to the following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> countries = [
      'Canada',
      'Germany',
      'India',
      'Taiwan, Province of China',
      'United States',
      'United Kingdom',
      'Kingdom of Saudi Arabia',
      'Bangladesh',
      'Vietnam',
      'Peru',
      'Italy'
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
      body: SizedBox(
          height: 200,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: PageView.builder(
              controller: PageController(
                  initialPage: 0,
                  viewportFraction: countries.length == 1 ? 1 : 0.80),
              itemCount: countries.length,
              padEnds: false,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 8, 10, 0),
                  color: Colors.lightBlue,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                    child: Center(child: Text(countries[index])),
                  ),
                );
              })),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as I am getting a preview on both sides. I only need it on the right side.